# How to connect mysql and php inside different container?

Tags: docker

I had two container called "**mysql-1**" and "**ubuntu-1**".

And I connect each other used

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3010:80 -itd --link mysql-1 --name=ubuntu-1 my-ubuntu-image:latest
```

Notice that **my-ubuntu-image** already had **nginx** and **php**, and I changed the **config** inside the **ubuntu-1** like following:

**default**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html/test/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9999;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                #fixes timeouts
                fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

**www.conf**

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9999
```

It works, when I try to run a simple php file without mysql.
But now I try to run a php file like following:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "123456";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

How to connect to mysql-1 container?

---

The environment Variables inside ubuntu-1 is like following:

```
MYSQL_1_PORT_33060_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.4:33060
MYSQL_1_PORT_33060_TCP_PORT=33060
MYSQL_1_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.4
HOSTNAME=632b415c540e
OLDPWD=/root
MYSQL_1_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
PWD=/var/www/html/test
HOME=/root
MYSQL_1_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT=3306
MYSQL_1_ENV_MYSQL_MAJOR=8.0
MYSQL_1_ENV_GOSU_VERSION=1.7
MYSQL_1_PORT_3306_TCP_PROTO=tcp
MYSQL_1_PORT_33060_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.4
MYSQL_1_ENV_MYSQL_VERSION=8.0.12-1debian9
MYSQL_1_PORT_33060_TCP_PROTO=tcp
TERM=xterm
SHLVL=1
MYSQL_1_NAME=/ubuntu-4/mysql-1
MYSQL_1_PORT_3306_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.4:3306
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
MYSQL_1_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.4:3306
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Connecting PHP container to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991743/docker-connecting-php-container-to-mysql)

Comment: Did you try to use the container name of your mysql as host instead of localhost?

Comment: @lvthillo Yes I tried, but not working.....

Comment: Are they deployed inside the same named bridge network?